# R - encontrar um valor específico na matriz

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldades para encontrar um valor específico em uma matriz. O problema é que minha matriz é muito grande para colocar aqui [360,181], então vou ter que resolver com um exemplo.

```
x<- matrix(1:50, ncol=5)
```

Preciso de algo como:

```
x[x==14]
```

E ele me retorne:

```
[4,2]
```

Onde respectivamente o meu valor 14 é encontrado na minha linha 4 e coluna 2.

Obrigada!

Comment: `which(x == 14, arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Comment: Muito obrigada Rui Barradas!